# In MVC 3 I have a View with 3 Partial Views. How do i get the 3rd partial view to display on the same page?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a view with 3 partial views.  The first partial view has a dropdown list.  You select something from the dropdown then the 2nd partial view will load right under it on the same page.

Then I have a search form (html.BeginForm) in my second partial view and when I submit the form I want to open up the 3rd partial view under the 2nd one.

The 3rd partial view has a kendo ui grid that takes a model.

The problem right now is that the 3rd partial view is getting rendered on a different page.

View:

```
 <section>
      <div id="searchpanel">
          @html.Partial("_1stPartial")
          <div id="2ndPartialDiv"></div>
          <div id="3rdPartialDiv"></div>
      </div>
 </section>
```

Partial View2:

```
<section>
  <div id="searchblock">
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions {  updateTargetId = "3rdPartialDiv"}))
          <fieldset>
          <ol>
            <li></li>
            <li>
             <input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearch"/>
            </li>
          </ol>
          </fieldset>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(model)
{
   //fill searchresults

   return PartialView("_3rdPartial", searchresults);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*is getting rendered on a different page*"?

Comment: can you post the code in the view?  Are you using AJAX to load up the 3rd view?

Comment: Justin, it peforms a full page post and it puts my partialview on a new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html.BeginForm will perform a full page post. I believe what you are after is Ajax.BeginForm.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Example:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("TheActionResultYouWantToInvokeThatWillReturnTheThirdView", "YourController", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "theIdOfTheDivForTheThirdView", OnSuccess = "doFunctionIfYouNeedTo", OnFailure = "ShowPopUpErrorIfYouWant" }))
     {

     }
```

Post code added edit:

This markup was invalid, and probably why UpdateTargetId is not finding the Div.

```
<section>
      <div id="searchpanel">
          @html.Partial("_1stPartial")
          <div id="2ndPartialDiv"></div>
          <div id="3rdPartialDiv"></div>
      </div>
 </section>
```

See closing speech marks on attributes.

Comment: I have been trying Ajax.BeginForm as well.  Seems to always go to my ActionResult in my controller and perform the same way.

Comment: return a PartialView from your controller

Comment: Jonesy is correct, Seth. Please post some code if you need more help.

Comment: I am returning a partialview from my controller.  Sorry about not posting code.  Our development is done in a completely isolated network.  I'll try to get an example on here for you.

Comment: Another thing might be that you've not specified an UpdateTargetId in your AjaxOptions of the form, that would also replace the whole page with the partial, IIRC.

Comment: Your attributes aren't closed.

Comment: That was just an error from me rewriting it on Stackoverflow.  Like i said i work on a isolated network and had to rewrite my code.

Answer (score 2):

What I understood from you question is that you're making a submit from the first `PartialView` and, if this was successfully, you'll show the 2nd one. Same for this one. If a successfully `POST` was made from the second `PartialView`, you want to show the 3rd one.

Why don't you do it with `Ajax`, from the client side?

```
 $.ajax ({
   type:'POST'
   data: {},
   success: function(response){
       $('.specific_div_container_for_previous_partial').hide();
       $('.specific_div_container_for_partial').html(response.Html);
       $('.specific_div_container_for_partial').show();
   },
   error: function(){
       // whatever
   }
 });
```

On the server side you'll return the rendered html with your `PartialView`. To render a `PartialView` in `variable` and send it the client side as a json object, please check out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955015/how-to-render-partial-view-in-controller-for-json)

**Update** - How to serialize form in jquery :

Please follow [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery)

Comment: I think i tried this too.  Would i have an on form submit event in javascript?  How do i pass my model data to my action in my controller from here?  Do i still use Ajax.BeginForm?

Comment: You can have a normal button on your form ( input type='button' ). If you do it like this, you should make a click handler in jquery. On that click handler you can send your form stringified and serialized JSON.stringify($('form').serialize)  in a data variable.   Btw : I've updated my question